# Can not see project on browser after vagrant provision

Tags: php, laravel-8

I can not see my project page on browser after do `vagrant provision` also I did `vagrant relaod --provision`

Comment: You should provide more details. What OS, what url, any error message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

move homestead folder to inside www folder or do php artisan serve than exit and try again vagrant provision